# Is there a conditionally convergent series with this property?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence $a_n$ whose associated series is merely conditionally convergent, not absolutely convergent, such that there is a permutation $f$ of the natural numbers, where $f$ moves infinitely many elements, such that the associated series of the rearranged sequence $a_{f(n)}$ is also convergent, and to the same sum?

Comment: Hint: consider $f$ such that $f(2n) = 2n+1$ and $f(2n+1) = 2n$.

Comment: "merely conditionally convergent, not absolutely convergent" is weird phrasing, as conditionally convergent series *cannot* be absolutely convergent. Also, is this question asking about the Riemann Series theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem which says that the terms of the sequence that were summed to form a conditionally convergent series can be rearranged so that the new sum of the rearranged terms can be *any* real number, dependent on how the terms are rearranged?

Comment: Somehow I did not see Damian Pavlyshyn's simple comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $1, -1, \frac12, -\frac12, \frac13, -\frac13,\cdots$. That is, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\lceil n/2\rceil}$ for all $n\ge1$.
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=0,\ \text{but} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2n=\infty.$$

Let $f$ switch $1$ and $2$, $3$ and $4$, $5$ and $6$, and so on. That is, $f(n)=n-(-1)^n$ for all $n$. The rearranged sequence $a_{f_n}$ is $-1, 1, -\frac12, \frac12, -\frac13,\frac13,\cdots$.

It is clear that the partial sums of the rearranged sequence also converges to $0$.

---

In fact, the same $f$ works for every sequence whose associated series is conditionally convergent.

In fact, as Adam Rubinson pointed out, every sequence whose associated series converges conditionally can be rearranged by a permutation that moves infinitely many elements to a sequence that conditionally converges to any given number as well as $\infty$ and $-\infty$. It can proved by a simple application of the Riemann rearrangement theorem.